# Why toggled classes does not animating the element and no error in console

Tags: javascript

Just trying to find out why when trying to add a toggle it gets added but the elements do not change the style and I do not get any errors.

```js
const burger = document.getElementsByClassName('barra')

const burgerArray = Array.from(burger)

function buttonChange() {
  for (i = 0; i < burgerArray.length; i++) {
    burgerArray[i].classList.toggle("change");
    console.log(burgerArray[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
.change b1 {
  background-color: red;
}

.change b2 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.change b3 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="buttonChange()" id="burgers" class="burger-menuu">
  <div class="barra" id="bar1"></div>
  <div class="barra" id="bar2"></div>
  <div class="barra" id="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How you define your bugerArray ?

Comment: Your selectors don't match your HTML. `.change b1` points to the b1 element in `<any class="change"><b1></b1></any>`. You must mean `.change#bar1`.

Comment: If i toggle .change#bar1 it will apply that custom to each one which is not desired.

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement - `it will apply that custom to each one which is not desired`

Comment: It would apply it to the one bar with the id #bar1. I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Sorry bad worded. I meant that it will apply the .change#bar1 only to bar1 and i would have to create the other two .change#bar2...and it will defeat the purpose of the for loop. Just trying to apply the change class to each one of the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this:

```js
const burgerArray = document.querySelectorAll(".barra");

function buttonChange() {
  for (i = 0; i < burgerArray.length; i++) {
    burgerArray[i].classList.toggle("change");
    console.log(burgerArray[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
#bar1.change {
  background-color: red;
}

#bar2.change {
  background-color: blue;
}

#bar3.change {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="buttonChange()" id="burgers" class="burger-menuu">
  <div class="barra" id="bar1">Sample Text 1</div>
  <div class="barra" id="bar2">Sample Text 2</div>
  <div class="barra" id="bar3">Sample Text 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for simplifying it a bit. It works with no errors too but it still does not change the style.

Comment: @FranciscoAzocar You can see test it with `Run code snippet`.... there might be some other code interfering can you share your complete code